# Will iphone app retrieve the pages from the server or from the app itself?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, cordova

I'm new to iPhone app development. I'm building app using phonegap by importing my all html css and javascript.

My doubt is if I'm using php at the backend can i make request similar to web from the iphone app. Will iPhone app retrieve the pages that is processed from the server?

Comment: You PHP will still run serverside, phonegap will not change that, so the information will be coming from the server.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap can access web sites listed in the WhiteList and obtain responses from them, e.g. web pages.
But such an application possibly will not pass AppStore approvement, because of it can get malicious dynamic content. (This is just my personal assumption.)